# Show all reminders in notification center

Tags: macos, notifications, reminders

The Reminders widget for Notifications Center on macOS Sierra only seems to show today's reminders.

I create a lot of reminders that don't always have a deadline or alarm set on them.

How can I show all of these all the time in the notifications center?

Comment: You could make your own app with a today widget that accesses the Reminders from the Reminders app and displays all of them; this actually wouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: @owlswipe Hey, that's a good idea!  Maybe a Watch extension, too.  I think I might give that a try....

Comment: @fsb Thanks :D. You could get fancy and add a way to check-off reminders as well as a shortcut button to create new ones.

Comment: @owlswipe Um...I'm not that good :-)

Comment: @owlswipe does apple really provide no way to do this themselves?

Comment: @theonlygusti I highly doubt they do. Their widgets aren't the most customizable.